# *** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000009c4010 ***

Tags: c

The program is supposed to read a sequence of numbers and print the same sequence but without any duplicates.

Their were others with my problem and I did try and implement what was discussed in those questions, but as far as I could tell I was not making the same mistakes and there was a lot of discussion focused on topics that I have little to no understanding of. I am still quite new to memory related things and I suppose programming in general and as you can probably tell from that lengthy error message I am indeed a student. Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

(I am sorry if this question is not formatted properly, I am quite new to posting on stack overflow).

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int len, alen = 0, temp, found = 0, *arr2;

    int *arr = calloc(alen, sizeof(int));

    scanf("%d:", &len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i == len-1) {
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            for (int j = 0; j < alen; j++) {
                if (temp == arr[j]) {
                    found = 1;
                }
            }
            if (found == 0) {
                alen++;
                arr2 = (int *) realloc(arr, sizeof(int)*alen);
                arr = arr2;
                arr[i] = temp;
                printf("%d ", temp);
            }
        } else {
            scanf("%d,", &temp);
            for (int j = 0; j < alen; j++) {
                if (temp == arr[j]) {
                    found = 1;
                }
            }
            if (found == 0) {
                alen++;
                arr2 = (int *) realloc(arr, sizeof(int)*alen);
                arr = arr2;
                arr[i] = temp;
                printf("%d ", temp);
            }
        }
        found = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Normal input:

```
8:1,2,4,3,2,1,7,8
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 4 3 7 8
```

Actual Output:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000009c4010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f261a3167e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x834aa)[0x7f261a3224aa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x179)[0x7f261a323839]
./a.out[0x400812]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f261a2bf830]
./a.out[0x400659]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 788482                             /home/student/impProg/lab7/noDuplicates/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 788482                             /home/student/impProg/lab7/noDuplicates/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 788482                             /home/student/impProg/lab7/noDuplicates/a.out
009c4000-009e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f2614000000-7f2614021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2614021000-7f2618000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f261a089000-7f261a09f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5251                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f261a09f000-7f261a29e000 ---p 00016000 08:01 5251                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f261a29e000-7f261a29f000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 5251                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f261a29f000-7f261a45f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 933                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f261a45f000-7f261a65f000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 933                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f261a65f000-7f261a663000 r--p 001c0000 08:01 933                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f261a663000-7f261a665000 rw-p 001c4000 08:01 933                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f261a665000-7f261a669000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f261a669000-7f261a68f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 922                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f261a875000-7f261a878000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f261a88d000-7f261a88e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f261a88e000-7f261a88f000 r--p 00025000 08:01 922                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f261a88f000-7f261a890000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 922                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f261a890000-7f261a891000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffca88e2000-7ffca8903000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffca8921000-7ffca8923000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffca8923000-7ffca8925000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
1 2 4 3 7 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: That error means you've written beyond your allocated memory.

Comment: Unrelated, but your main IF...ELSE clause has duplicated content and is useless. If you learn to use a debugger it will pretty much eliminate the need to ask similar questions.

Comment: `I am sorry if this question is not formatted properly` - This is a good question. You presented your code - a smallest possible reproducible example, your input, the expected output, and what happens upon execution. To follow the spirit of this forum, the only thing that is lacking is a question - something like "How do I fix my code?" or "Where is the error in my code?" or "Why executing my code results in this error?"

Comment: I think @KamilCuk's answer pretty much hits the nail on the head--I'd just like to chime in with a quick tool suggestion: If you use the clang compiler and compile with `-fsanitize=asan -g -Og`, you'll get a good amount of additional debug data right when the overflow happens (as opposed to some time later when you try to allocate more memory). It's a bit hard to understand at first but I strongly recommend trying it out on this sample and seeing if you can correlate what you see to the findings presented in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr[i] = temp;
```

`i` is the iterator over input numbers, not iterator over `arr`. You meant to set the last new array element:

```
arr[alen - 1] = temp;
```

Accessing array out of bounds is undefined behavior.

Couple of fast notes:

- Rather then handling two separate cases with `scanf("%d,"` and `scanf("%d"`, just do `scanf("%d"`  to get the number and read the comma with `getchar`, ex. `int c = getchar(); if (c != ',') { printf("End of input"); }`.
- Your code lacks handling allocation errors. `arr = realloc(...); if (arr == NULL) { handle_error(); }`.
- Your code lacks handling input errors. `int a = scanf("%d", ...); if (a != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input\n"); abort(); }`.